# Looking for advice on how to avoid a Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have in my application a similar situation to this:

```
public class Example {

private static A aClass = new A();
private static B bClass = new B();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bClass.start();
        }
    }, ">>>>>>>>>>").start();


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            aClass.start();
        }
    }, "__________").start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    detectDeadlock();
}

private static void detectDeadlock() {
    ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long[] threadIds = threadBean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
    int deadlockedThreads = threadIds != null? threadIds.length : 0;
    System.out.println("Number of deadlocked threads: " + deadlockedThreads);
}

private static class A {
    private final Object aLock = new Object();

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-start; waiting for aLock");
        synchronized (aLock) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-start; acquired aLock");
            bClass.synchronizedMethod();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-start; release aLock");
    }

    public void synchronizedMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-synchronizedMethod; waiting for aLock");
        synchronized (aLock) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-synchronizedMethod; acquired aLock");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "A-synchronizedMethod; release aLock");
    }
}

private static class B {
    private final Object bLock = new Object();

    public void synchronizedMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "B-synchronizedMethod; waiting for bLock");
        synchronized (bLock) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "B-synchronizedMethod; acquired bLock");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "B-synchronizedMethod; release bLock");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + "B-Start; waiting for bLock");
        synchronized (bLock) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "B-Start; acquired bLock");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            aClass.synchronizedMethod();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+ " " + "B-Start; released bLock");
    }
}
```

}

the output for this snippet would be something like this:

```
Thread[>>>>>>>>>>,5,main] B-Start; waiting for bLock
Thread[>>>>>>>>>>,5,main] B-Start; acquired bLock
Thread[__________,5,main] A-start; waiting for aLock
Thread[__________,5,main] A-start; acquired aLock
Thread[__________,5,main] B-synchronizedMethod; waiting for bLock
Thread[>>>>>>>>>>,5,main] A-synchronizedMethod; waiting for aLock
Number of deadlocked threads: 2
```

I'm looking for some guidance for this deadlock situation.

Can you please advice me how to avoid this deadlock?

Comment: One solution is to make sure you always acquire the locks in the same order - for example each lock could have a unique id and you always lock the smaller id first or something like that.

Comment: This is the classic deadlock example in computer science. Did you [google it](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/7_Deadlocks.html)? The techniques are well-researched, well-established and well-documented.

Comment: Your question reminds me of an old joke: The patient says, "Doctor! Doctor! It hurts when I do this...," and the doctor replies, "Well, don't _do_ that!".  Your code snippet looks like a textbook example of what _not_ to do if you wish to avoid a deadlock. It doesn't attempt to solve any problem or produce any useful output. You can't _fix_ it because if it didn't deadlock, then it would not do anything at all. If you don't want a deadlock, then don't run the program.

Comment: What is it that you _really_ want to know? If you want to understand what the example is showing you, it is showing you that two threads can deadlock if each of them tries to acquire the same two locks, but they do it in the opposite order from each other. And, it hints at the fact that it you can accidentally write code like that if you pass around objects that each contain their own internal locks.

Comment: Well, the flows and the code is not that simple and obvious as exemplified above. I tried to strip it down as much as I can to the bare minimum in order to provide an example. In the end I chose to use a global shared lock. See my answer. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I chose to use a global lock that would be shared by both instances of A and B.

The code would look something like this:

```
 private static class Lock {
    private static Lock lock = new Lock();
    private Lock(){}
    public static Lock getLock() {return lock;}
}

private static class A {
    private final Object aLock = Lock.getLock();
    // ...
}

private static class B {
    private final Object bLock = Lock.getLock();
    // ...
}
```